# Why does page jump work in Internet Explorer but Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html

I am using this code below, the "Click Here To View Warranty Details" link does a page jump down the page, which after uploading to ebay works in IE but not Mozilla, is there any code that I can place that will do a page jump that will work on all browsers?

Here is the live link (only on this item as a test)

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Metra-70-1002-1988-1996-Dodge-Jeep-In-Dash-Radio-Installation-Wire-Harness-/350683730934?MfcISAPICommand=ViewItem

```
<a href="#policies">Click Here To View Warranty Details</a> </p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
        <center>
        <p class="pad"><b>Click to enlarge (Photos will open in a new window)</b><br />
        ##ITEM_IMAGES_HORT_M##</p>
        </center>
        <h3>Product Description</h3>
        <div class="pad2">
        <table style="border: black 1px solid;" cellpadding="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <p>##ITEM_DESCRIPTION_HTML##</p>
                    <p><strong><span style="font-size: 24px;">Specifications:&nbsp;</span></strong></p>
                    <p>##ITEM_ATTRIBUTES##</p>
                    <p>##CUSTOM1## </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div id="listing-lower">
        <h2 class="item_title"><img alt="" src="http://www.audiosavings.com/content/ebay/newtemplate/tru_policies.jpg" /></h2>
        <a href="" name="policies">&nbsp;</a>
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="infoTabs"><a id="infoTabs"><!-- tab 1 --></a><a name="shipping"></a>
        <div id="tab1">
        <ul class="tablinks">
            <li><span>Shipping</span> </li>
            <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="return show('tab2')">Payment</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="return show('tab3')">Return Policy</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="return show('tab4')">General Info</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="return show('tab5')">Intl. Shipping</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <h4 class="tabtitle">Shipping</h4>
        <ul class="tabinfo">
            <ul class="tabinfo">
                <li><strong><span style="color: #293d86;">Shipping is FREE!<br />
                </span></strong>Free shipping to the 48 continental&nbsp;US&nbsp;is done with ##ITEM_DEFAULT_SHIPPING_METHOD_DESCRIPTION##<br />
                - Orders Tues-Friday - Pay by 1:00 PM EST and get SAME DAY SHIPPING!<br />
                - Orders Sat - Sunday - Ships Monday<br />
                - Orders Monday - Ships Monday or Tuesday <br />
```

Comment: Try removing the `href=""` portion. name anchors should generally not need them. they're an anchor target, not a source of anchors themselves.

Comment: I applied what marc said, It might be a different issue, when I view the source in internet explorer I see the link, when I view source in Mozilla I cant find the link or text its as if it is a totally different code, I dont know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

Your anchor for the policies should be

```
 <a id="policies">
```

instead of the name attribute.

*Edit*
As Marc B mentionned: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Comment: mmm no: `<a id="policies">`. <a name="policies"> works with IE but will not work with Firefox. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Comment: `<a id="policies">` but it mostly has to do with the Doctype of your document. XHTML and HTML5 uses `id`. On IE, Chrome and FF with no Doctype specified, `id` works.

Answer (score 4):

Anchors are supposed to be `id=""` attributes, not `name=""`.

Comment: Only in html5, though. <=4.x it has to be name="..."